# How to access and add polylines to multiple maps using vue2leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

I'm trying to create a page containing multiple maps with polylines by using v-for. I tried to use the leaflet:load event to call a method after the map has been loaded, but the event doesn't seem to exist.

Here is my idea, although I know it doesn't work.

Does anyone have some suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="map in maps" :key="map.id">
            <l-map style="height:500px; width:500px" 
                   @leaflet:load="insertPolyline">
                <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"/>
            </l-map>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script >
import { LMap, LPolyline, LTileLayer} from 'vue2-leaflet';

export default {
components: {
    LMap,
    LPolyline,
    LTileLayer
  },
data() {
    return {
        mapsLoaded: false,
        maps: [],
        url:'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attribution:'&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> 
                     contributors',
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.maps.push('test1')
    this.maps.push('test2')
    this.maps.push('test3')
},

methods: {
    insertPolyline: function(event) {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            var map = event.target.mapObject
            var polyline = require( 'google-polyline' )
            var points = polyline.decode( '_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@' )
            L.polyline(points, {
            color: 'blue',
            weight: 5,
            opacity: .7,
            lineJoin: 'round'
            }).addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(points);
        })
    }
}
}
</script>
<style>
 @import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. When inside a v-for you can use the same ref and it will create an array using that ref. Then by using an index, it's possible to step through the array and add the polylines

Here's the code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="n in numberOfMaps" :key="n.id">
            <l-map ref="map" style="height:500px; width:500px" 
                   @leaflet:load="insertPolyline">
                <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"/>
            </l-map>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script >
import { LMap, LPolyline, LTileLayer} from 'vue2-leaflet';

export default {
components: {
    LMap,
    LPolyline,
    LTileLayer
  },
data() {
    return {
        mapsLoaded: false,
        url:'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        attribution:'&copy; <a 
        href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
        numberOfMaps: 0,
        mapIndex: 0
    }
},

mounted() {
    this.numberOfMaps = 5
},

methods: {
    insertPolyline: function() {
        var map = this.$refs.map[this.mapIndex++].mapObject
        var polyline = require( 'google-polyline' )
        var points = polyline.decode( '_p~iF~ps|U_ulLnnqC_mqNvxq`@' )
        L.polyline(points, {
        color: 'blue',
        weight: 5,
        opacity: .7,
        lineJoin: 'round'
        }).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(points);
    }
}
}
</script>
<style>
 @import "~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
</style>
```